# Batch FOR loop IF and SET conflict

Tags: batch-file

So, I was writing a small batch-file game, and came across this problem in the FOR loop.
This is a small chunk of my code.
If the player picks-up the rock, check if it is on the table, then put it in your pack.
The problem is the SET command doesn't work.
I guess that lines executes as : set %table1%=empty  not : set table1=empty.

I feel like there is a simple solution to this problem, I've trying for a few days in my spare time, but haven't gotten it.
Any help is appreciated!

```
set take=rock
set table1=box
set table2=rock
set table3=wrench

for %%x in (%table1% %table2% %table3%) do (

    if %%x==%take% (
        set %%x=empty
        set pack=%%x
        goto tableRoom
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is `set %%x=empty` for a logical reason: the `for` loop is iterating over the list of the values inside the `table` variables, not over the name of the variables so you can not change the value of the variable when you don't have a reference to the variable, you have the value inside it.

Enabling delayed expansion and iterating over the names of the variables can solve the problem

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "take=rock"
    set "table1=box"
    set "table2=rock"
    set "table3=wrench"

    for %%x in (table1 table2 table3) do (
        if "!%%x!"=="%take%" (
            set "%%x=empty"
            set "pack=%take%"
            goto tableRoom
        )
    )

:tableRoom
    set table
    exit /b
```

`%%x` will hold the name of the variable, so when `!%%x!` is executed it will be something like `!table1!`, retrieving the value inside the variable (when delayed expansion is enabled).

If the names of the used variables (`table...`) does not collide with anything else, and you don't want to use delayed expansion, it is possible to take the output of `set table` command (the list the variables with its values) and process this list with a `for /f` command, splitting the command output, separating variable name and value

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "take=rock"
    set "table1=box"
    set "table2=rock"
    set "table3=wrench"

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set table') do (
        if "%%b"=="%take%" (
            set "%%a=empty"
            set "pack=%take%"
            goto tableRoom
        )
    )

:tableRoom
    set table
    exit /b
```

The output of `set` command contains `var=value`. Each of the lines is splitted using the `=` as a delimiter to get two tokens (`tokens=1,*`). `%%a` will hold the first token (the variable name) and `%%b` the rest of the line (the value in the variable)

Comment: Aha! Your first example is what I was looking for! Thank you very much!  When I originally tried the FOR loop with table1 not %table1%, SET worked but IF didn't.  !%%x! fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to now which table you're testing in your `FOR` loop and
set directly the `table!N!` as empty :

```
set take=rock
set table1=box
set table2=rock
set table3=wrench

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $c=1
for %%x in (%table1% %table2% %table3%) do (
    if %%x==%take% (
        set table!$c!=empty
        set pack=%%x
        goto tableRoom
)
set /a $c+=1
)

:tableroom
echo table2 is now : %table2%
```

Comment: I like this idea, and it defiantly solves this problem. Thank You! But is there a simple way to get : if %%x==whatever and set %%x=whatever both to work in the same FOR loop, I feel like this will limit me further down the road.